# beamer to show nested-subitem when all (non-nested) items covered

Tags: beamer, itemize, overlays, transparency

I am trying to get an alternating highlighting effect between `\itemize` items and subitems (which are just nested `itemize` items), but there is an issue in that when all of the non-nested items are hidden the nested subitem fails to show.  The desired effect is that:

- Overlay #1: the non-nested items will be initially shown in full opacity while the nested subitem will be initially shown as transparent
- Overlay #2: the non-nested items are hidden as transparent items, while the nested sub-item is shown in full opacity
- Overlay #3: all items are shown in full opacity

A minimal working example to reproduce the issue (using code that reflects what I'm trying to achieve):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1,3>{outside}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<2->{inside}
        \end{itemize}
        \item<1,3>{outside}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that the issue seems to be specifically at the last non-nested item before the nested itemize environment. I.e., the issue above is that the sub-item fails perform the overlay spec of appearing at slide #2, but this spec works in the example below when the non-nested item above it is also displayed during slide #2 (instead of above where it is hidden during slide #2):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<1->{outside}  % <---- this is the difference from above
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<2->{inside}
        \end{itemize}
        \item<1,3>{outside}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `\visible` with your `\item`s

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item\visible<1,3>{outside}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item\visible<2->{inside}
        \end{itemize}
        \item\visible<1,3>{outside}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked (although I use `\uncover` instead of `\visible`).

Comment: @DanielNaftalovich You're welcome. I wasn't sure if transparent meant covered or invisible, but I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hack that almost accomplishes the intention, but non-ideal because the bullet does not become transparent (and also is a hassle to code)

```
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item{\temporal<2>{outside}{\color{black!15}{outside}}{outside}}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<->{inside}
        \end{itemize}
        \item<1,3>{later}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```